# On a real square matrix of order $10$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, matrix-rank, characteristic-polynomial

Let $M_{10}$ be the set of $10×10$ real matrices; if $U\in M_{10}$, then let $\rho(U)=rank(U)$.

Which of the followings are true for every $A\in M_{10}$?

$(1)\rho(A^8)=\rho(A^9)$

$(2)\rho(A^9)=\rho(A^{10})$

$(3)\rho(A^{10})=\rho(A^{11})$

$(4)\rho(A^8)=\rho(A^7)$

I am able to discard options $(1),(2)$ &$ (4)$ by taking nilpotent matrices of order $9,10$ & $8$ respectively. This leaves $(3)$ as true but I am finding it difficult to write a general proof.

I think characteristics polynomial can be used.

Can you give any suggestions? Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\rho$ ?

Comment: rank of the matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $\rho(A^{10})$ is different from $0$ implies that there exists $k$ such that  $\rho(A^{k}) =  \rho(A^{k-1})$.  The reason is that the rank can only decrease, and cannot be negative.

Then $\rho(A^{k+1})$ cannot be lower than  $\rho(A^{k}).$

If $\rho(A^{10}) = 0$ then the problem is directly solved.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can see the reason for the existence of $k$ satisfying what you have mentioned . But why may not it happen that $\rho(A^{11})\lt \rho(A^{10})$ ?

Comment: If $\rho(A^{k}) =  \rho(A^{k-1})$, it implies that the image of $A^{k-1}$ has no element in $Ker A$, except null vector of course. As the image is $A^{k}$ is included in the image of $A^{k-1}$, then both images are equal etc. Then the rank cannot decrease anymore when $k$ increases. In other words, $Im(A^k) = Im(A^{k+1}) = Im(A^{k+2}) = \dots$

Comment: Absolutely !!  That 's the point I was missing. Anyway , I was thinking about generalising this . Can it be said that for any square matrix $A$ of order $n$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ ,we must have $\rho(A^n)=\rho(A^{n+1})$. ?

Comment: I think so, we can generalise. In the demonstration, I don't use the fact that $n = 10$ !

Comment: Yes .Thanks again for your help.